# Let $E$ be the set of all $x \in [0,1]$ whose decimal expansion contains only the digits 4 and 7. Is $E$ compact? - Explanation

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, compactness

Let $E$ be the set of all $x \in [0,1]$ whose decimal expansion contains only the digits 4 and 7. Is $E$ compact?

This question comes from Baby Rudin Ch.2 - 2.17.

I have a solution I found for the question and this is what my questions revolve around. I believe I have the correct understanding of what was set out to be accomplished in order to prove the claim (I will  type my "understanding"  below). But I am a little lost in how the bounds that were stated were derived.

As such here is the solution:

[image]

**My understanding:** In order to show that $E$ is compact we have to show closed and boundedness of the set. Boundedness is obvious, to show it is closed we show that $E^{c} =  [0,1] -E $ is open. This is accomplished by showing that any point $y \in E$ will be at the minimum a fixed distance away from every point of $E^{c}$ which we can then use to choose $\epsilon$ to always be less than this distance. which will show that $E^{c}$ is open (this is a new technique to show openess that I've seen). But after concluding $E^{c}$ is open then we can conclude $E$ is closed.

**Questions:**

i) How are these bounds constructed? i.e how is $ \epsilon \leq \frac{7}{9} 10^{-m}$ found? And as such how do the other two bounds follow? i.e: $\frac{2}{9 \cdot 10^{m}}$

ii) As mentioned above is this another wy to show a point is an interior point? i.e: by showing no point from outside the set could be a fixed distance away?

iii) How is it we are allowed to pick our $\epsilon$ in these sorts of questions? Is it because we are trying to establish a fact about a certain collection of elements and as such this $\epsilon$ works only for this set?

Comment: Just observing that $[0,1]\cong\{0,1,\ldots,9\}^{\omega}$ and your subset is $\{4,7\}^{\omega}$.

Comment: I would prove the claim by recognizing your set as the intersection of (infinitely many) closed sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple application of a geometric sum; as noted $|x_k-y_k|\leq7$ and so
$$\varepsilon=\sum_{k\geq m+1}10^{-k}|x_k-y_k|\leq7\sum_{k\geq m+1}10^{-k}=\frac{7}{9}10^{-m}.$$
Then plugging this back into the earlier inequality yields
$$|x-y|\geq10^{-m}-\varepsilon=\frac{2}{9}10^{-m}.$$

As for the structure of the proof; 
the proof shows that $E$ is closed by showing that $E^c$ is open, which by definition means that every for $x\in E^c$ there is an open interval around $x$ that is entirely contained in $E^c$.

That such an interval exists is proved by showing that for every $x\in E^c$, every element of $E$ is more than some given distance $\tfrac{1}{9\cdot10^n}$ apart from $x$, where $n$ depends only on $x$. This means the open interval $(x-\tfrac{1}{9\cdot10^n},x+\tfrac{1}{9\cdot10^n})$ is entirely contained in $E^c$.

Comment: I suspected that, but when I worked it out I got: $\frac{1}{1 -\frac{1}{10}} = \frac{10}{9}$ so how does $10^{-m}$ appear ?

Comment: Where did you get that numerator? The sum starts at $k=m+1$ so the numerator should be $10^{-m-1}$.

Comment: My issue with the expression is how does $7\sum_{k\geq m+1}10^{-k}  =\frac{7}{9}10^{-m}$ when $7\sum_{k\geq m+1}10^{-k} = 7(\frac{1}{1 -\frac{1}{10}}) = 7(\frac{10}{9})$ since it is an infinite geometric series.

Comment: No; are you familiar with the closed form of a geometric series? In this case
$$(1-10^{-1})\sum_{k\geq m+1}10^{-k}=10^{-m-1},$$
and so the sum evaluates to $\tfrac{10^{-m-1}}{1-10^{-1}}=\tfrac{1}{9}10^{-m}$. See alse the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula); here $r=\tfrac{1}{10}$ and $a=7\cdot10^{-m-1}$.

Comment: I should be since I am doing Analysis, but it doesn't ring a bell. Is there a quick link you could suggest for me to read up on it?

Comment: One last quick question. How did $(1-10^{-1})$  fall into the denominator in your expression:$ \tfrac{10^{-m-1}}{1-10^{-1}}=\tfrac{1}{9}10^{-m}$ ?  Edit:  You just divided it over.....

Comment: $$\frac{10^{-m-1}}{1-10^{-1}}=\frac{10}{10}\frac{10^{-m-1}}{1-10^{-1}}=\frac{10^{-m}}{10-1}=\frac{10^{-m}}{9}.$$

Comment: Thank You for your time.